# Не могу добавить элемент в коллекцию

Tags: excel, vba

Есть такой код макроса. Почему он не добавляет элементы в коллекцию?
Никаких логов/ошибок не выдает. Просто не добавляет и всё.

```
Dim cellRanges, cValues As Collection
Dim it1, it2, it3, it4, it5, it6, it7, it8 As String
it1 = "L3"
it2 = "J18"
it3 = "J19"
it4 = "J20"
it5 = "K23"
it6 = "J24"
it7 = "B86"
it8 = "K86"
cellRanges.Add (it1)
cellRanges.Add (it2)
cellRanges.Add (it3)
cellRanges.Add (it4)
cellRanges.Add (it5)
cellRanges.Add (it6)
cellRanges.Add (it7)
cellRanges.Add (it8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что если вы пишете:

```
Dim cellRanges, cValues As Collection
```

То вы объявляете как коллекцию только переменную `cValues`. В VBA (в отличие от других ЯП, где можно написать, например, `String a, b, c`, объявляя несколько переменных одного типа) нужно каждый раз после объявлении переменной указывать её тип.

Поправьте начало макроса на:

```
Dim cellRanges As New Collection, cValues As New Collection 'объявление и создание
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а формат объявлеиния `As New` вместо `As`  касается только Коллекций?

Comment: @Skotinin, `As New` - это вообще другое и, вероятно, тебе не нужно. Просто создай новую коллекцию в следующей строки и присвой её переменной.

Comment: Разобрался. `As` указывает на тип объявленной переменной, `As New` создает экземпляр класса Collection. Не выспался, наверно.